# Modern phonetics and the word "sure"

Tags: phonetics

How true is it that there is a modern phonetical tendency in the English language to pronounce the word "sure" rather like"shore", but not a classical "sure"?

Comment: I don't want to close it as off-topic, I want to close it as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 5):

There being no clearly defined classical pronunciation of "sure", it's unclear what you mean by the classical pronunciation. But there shore is lowering. One variable is whether or not there is an *r* of any kind. Another is what vowel comes after [ʃ]: the pronunciation could be [ʃɹ̩] or [ʃʊɹ]. In the US, there is a spreading tendency to lower [ʊ] to [ɔ] before *r*, so [ʃɔɹ] is common, and can this combine with r-dropping so that you get [ʃo] or [ʃɔə]. You also encounter [tɔɹ] which means both "tour" and "tore". In the Midwest, tour-lowering has spread significantly in the past 20 or so years.